# Make page scroll on only first radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My page shows a div after a radio button from id="yourgoal" is clicked. I'd like the page to scroll to that div only on the first time a button in "yourgoal" is clicked. Here is the code I am using. I don't want the page to scroll to the div after the first click though.

```
$('input:radio[name="yourgoal"]').change(function() {
                 if ($('#calculations1').css('display') == 'none') {
                            $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $("#scrollto").offset().top
                            }, 1500);

                    }
```

The problem is, it breaks the rest of the functions I have on .change(). I don't want to put all the functions after the scroll within the if and then again into an else {} statement as that seems like a ton of redundant code (it also breaks it)? How do I just do a simple if statement which doesn't affect the rest of the actions within the .change function?

Maybe there is a simpler solution and I am overthinking this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input:radio[name="yourgoal"]').one('change',
    function () {
        if ($('#calculations1').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#scrollto").offset().top
            }, 1500);
        }
    }
);
```

I recommend using one. After first time event is triggered it is automatically removed.

If you have more code to go in that change that needs to stay after the first change, you can use event namespacing and attach more than one change.

```
$('input:radio[name="yourgoal"]').one('change.firstChange',
    function () {
        if ($('#calculations1').css('display') == 'none') {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#scrollto").offset().top
            }, 1500);
        }
    }
);
$('input:radio[name="yourgoal"]').on('change.allChanges',
    function () {
        // All your other code that stays attached
    }
);
```

EDIT: Seems like one won't work since that 'one' event will be attached to each radio button that has name yourgoal, so it will scroll once for each first radio button click individually but you can do this if you only want to scroll the first time a radio button is selected and not upon the first selection of other radio buttons that all share the yourgoal name.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/31s3LLjL/3/

```
$('input:radio[name="yourgoal"]').on('change.firstChange',
    function () {
        $('input:radio[name="yourgoal"]').off('change.firstChange');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#scrollto").offset().top
        }, 1500);
    }
);
$('input:radio[name="yourgoal"]').on('change.allChanges',
    function () {
        // Other change stuff
    }
);
```

Comment: Wow awesome! So for the rest of the changes do I really need to use: $('input:radio[name="yourgoal"]').on('change.allChanges', or I can keep the original .change(function() code I already have? Actually, just going to test. Thanks so much!

Comment: @JohnC, no you don't need to namespace the other one. I just did it to make the code more clear what each event was for. See: http://jsfiddle.net/31s3LLjL/4/

Comment: it seemed it was necessary. The rest of the functions broke I didn't use your "on('change.allChanges'," version and kept my old .change(function(). Good to know! Thanks again

Comment: No problem!! Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) to prevent execution of subscribed callbacks on specific event.

```
$('input:radio[name="yourgoal"]').one('change',function(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  if ($('#calculations1').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#scrollto").offset().top
    }, 1500);
  }
});
```

Just make sure that your code prepends all other `change` handler definitions.